# Mongoid: correctly using association callbacks with forms

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid3

I have come across a problem which I am struggling to solve elegantly. I am more versed in RDBMSs so the way I am doing things may not be ideal.

**What I am doing:**
I am having to keep track of items within a HABTM association. Whats more, there is a condition on the count as only items that are 'active' are counted. I have successfully used the association callbacks to track additions and removals from the collection.

**The problem:**
I am also adding items to the collection via forms by setting the opposite instance's id to the form as a hidden field. This works fine, however the problem is that this adds the opposite instance straight to the collection without invoking the callback (the age old problem).

**My Question:**
Is there a more elegant way to add add instances to the collection that invokes the callback?

Let me know if you need any more specific examples and I'll happily provide some.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using the following mongoid3 callbacks?

- after_add
- after_remove
- before_add
- before_remove

More information [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#relation_callbacks)

Comment: That's how I currently solve the problem. It is less than optimal because I have to do a lot of state management as I have to figure out whether the association callback has been invoked, in which case it should skip the model callbacks.
I was looking for a solution with assoc. callback only. I understand that this may not exists however thought it worthwhile to ask you guys.